# Web.config not being used in IIS for WCF

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config

I have a WCF service running in IIS. I followed this tutorial to host it in IIS: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis

I have a simple Web.config file that is not being recognized by the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyApp.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="MyApp.IService1" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I run this line of code I get an error: Object not set to an instance of an object:

```
var test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext"];
var x = test.ToString();
```

I have the Web.config file in the same folder as the DLL. The whole service is in the wwwroot.

Is there some setting I'm missing to make the web.config actually work? Is there something in IIS I need to set for it to use the web.config? What do I do to get IIS to recognize my web.config?

Comment: Is this a class library?  If it is, you need to move the settings to the config file of the application, as class libraries don't use config files on their own.

Comment: Yes, it is a service class library. Not sure what you mean by the config file of the application. Is that the app.config?

Comment: "I have the Web.config file in the same folder as the DLL." That's wrong. `web.config` is expected to be in the root folder of the IIS application, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrad/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools/

Comment: the config file should build in the bin folder for your configuration (dev, prod, etc..). go to the properties and make sure Copy to Output Directory says Copy always.

Comment: Is the Web.config file in the root of the application per step 10: "Create a file named "Web.config" in the application directory and add the following configuration code into the file. At runtime, the WCF infrastructure uses the information to construct an endpoint that client applications can communicate with."?  I.e., if the directory path is something like C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Myservice, then the Web.config file should be in the MyService folder.

Comment: Thanks everyone that was my problem had it in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure of your app.config files taking effect is the main reason for this problem.
As mentioned in the example.

- > Create a new file named "service.svc" in the application directory
- > Create a file named "Web.config" in the application directory

If you want to host the wcf service library project in IIS, you should follow these steps.

You have to move your configuration code into the configuration file recognized by your hosting environment. And then you will be able to read the web.config correctly.

> Yes, it is a service class library. Not sure what you mean by the config file of the application. Is that the app.config?

Here is official document about how to deploy the wcf service library.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/deploying-a-wcf-library-project

Generally speaking, we use the app.config  in the windows service hosting-environment for wcf.